# iOS push notification received but no badge value

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

In my iOS Swift app i can send push notifications with this php code:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'APPNAME');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) 
{
    exit("Failed to connect: ".$err." ".$errstr." ". PHP_EOL);
}

$body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is a test', 'badge' => "1", 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', DEVICE_TOKEN) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
```

I successfully receive the message, with the sound, but my app icon gets not badge value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set your badge with a string value :

```
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is a test', 'badge' => "1", 'sound' => 'default');
```

According to the description of payload keys from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1), the value associated with the key `badge` must be a number. Replace it with an integer value :

```
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is a test', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
```

Comment: ahhh okay - this was my mistake. now it works ! thx, but can i set an dynamic value, too? for the case the user get 2 notifications, i would like to set the actual badge number + 1

Comment: If the application isn't launched, you can just set the value, the count must be saved server-side. If the application is started, you can set the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property of `UIApplication` (useful for local notifications which can be computed from the client side).

Answer (score 1):

Use `'badge' => 1` and not `'badge' => "1"`

Answer (score 0):

Hey @GhostStack make sure you have to register for alert/sound and badge in `applicationDodFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```